# React native zoomclone app, how to connect different devices via reactapp and able to render other devices streams

Tags: react-native, express, socket.io, webrtc, peerjs

how to connect other devices via **socketio** and **webrtc** in a **react native app**. I have tried using `API_URL = my pc's ip address || 5000`, can anyone tell me how to connect other android devices after installing the react native app. I am done with the coding part, but in node server I am not able to see any **user connected**, or mediadetails, or `roomID` or `deviceID`? I am using nodejs as backend.

I have tried creating `peerServer =new Peer(undefined,{host:"/",port:443})` object inside async function.

I am not able to get massage connected client on the server side. i.e
**socket.on('connection', () => console.log('connected client'));** this line of code is not able to execute correctly.

```
server.js code




const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const socketio = require('socket.io');
const morgan = require('morgan');

const {ExpressPeerServer} = require('peer');
const { join } = require('path');

const app = express();

const server = http.createServer(app)
const io = socketio(server).sockets;


// Borderparser
app.use(express.json());

const customGenerationFunction = () =>
(Math.random().toString(36) + "00000000000000000").substr(2,16);


const peerServer = ExpressPeerServer(server, {
        debug: true,
        path:'/',
        generateClientId: customGenerationFunction,

});

app.use("/mypeer", peerServer);

io.on('connection', function (socket){
    socket.on('join-room', ({roomID, userId}) => {
        socket.join(roomID);
        socket.to(roomID).broadcast.emit("user-connected", userId);
    });
});


const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server is running on port 
${port}`))

--------------------video-action.js codes-------------------------------

import IO from 'socket.io-client';
import Peer from 'react-native-peerjs'; 
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import {mediaDevices} from 'react-native-webrtc';

import  {ADD_STREAM, MY_STREAM, ADD_REMOTE_STREAM} from './types';
//* api uri*/
export const API_URI = `http://192.168.01.36:5000`;

//**socket config */
export const socket = IO(`${API_URI}`,{
forceNew: true
})

peerServer =new Peer(undefined,
    {
        host:'192.168.216.202',
        secure: false,
        port:5000,
        path: '/mypeer',
    }) 

peerServer.on('error', console.log);

socket.on('connection', () => console.log('connected client'));

export const joinRoom = (stream) => async (dispatch) => {

const roomID = 'ahdbflarlkhnlfkjvaerbjhfbjds';



//set my own stream
dispatch({type: MY_STREAM, payload: stream});

//open a connection to our server
peerServer.on('open', (userId) => {
socket.emit('join-room', {userId, roomID});
});

socket.on('user-connected', (userId) => {
connectToNewUser(userId, stream, dispatch)
});

// recieve a call
peerServer.on('call', (call) => {
call.answer(stream);

// stream back the call
call.on('stream', (stream) => {
    dispatch({type: ADD_STREAM, payload: stream});
    });
});
};

function connectToNewUser(userId, stream, dispatch) {
const call = peerServer.call(userId, stream);



}
```